# attempt to insert section 3 but there are only 3 sections after the update

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, reloaddata

I have Tableview with N number of section in which 0,1 sections are fix. that will never deleted from tableview. But from starting of section 2 to N number of sections, it can be deleted or inserted. and from 2nd section to N sections -> Each sections have number of rows also.
I have searching functionality on this 2nd section to N number of sections. 
 Here is the whole code 
 
**1. this is the count dic which contain number of row for each sections ["section" : "no of rows"]**

```
self.countDic.updateValue(1, forKey: "0")
self.countDic.updateValue(0, forKey: "1")
for i in 0..<arra1.count {
    self.countDic.updateValue(array.count, forKey: "\(i + 2)")//[index : arraylist.count]
}
```

**2. Here is the Tableview Methods which return sections and rows**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return countDic["\(section)"]!
}
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return countDic.count
}
```

**3. Here is the Searching and table reload code**

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    let newString = NSString(string: textField.text!).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)

    if (newString.isEmpty) {
        FilterStr = ""
    } else {
        FilterStr = newString
    }

    let namesBeginningWithLetterPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "(title1 CONTAINS[cd] $letter)")

    let arr : [Today_ActivityModel] = (Today_Activity_Data as NSArray).filtered(using: namesBeginningWithLetterPredicate.withSubstitutionVariables(["letter": FilterStr])) as! [Today_ActivityModel]
    if FilterStr == "" {
        self.countDic.removeAll()

        FilterData.removeAll()
        //self.GetRecordsCityWiseFilter(ArrayList: self.Today_Activity_Data)
    } else {
        if arr.count >= 0 {

            FilterData.removeAll()
            //self.GetRecordsCityWiseFilter(ArrayList: arr )
        } else {

            self.countDic.removeAll()

            FilterData.removeAll()
            //self.GetRecordsCityWiseFilter(ArrayList: self.Today_Activity_Data)
        }
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        UIView.performWithoutAnimation {

            let indexSet = IndexSet(integersIn: 2..<self.TblView.numberOfSections)
            self.TblView.reloadSections(indexSet, with: .bottom)
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

While reloading the table i m getting **attempt to insert section 3 but there are only 3 sections after the update** 
Can anyone help me how to resolve this?

Comment: why don't you use two different array for handling all this things
one is for top 2 section and second one is for rest of other sections

Comment: i will take two different array for top and last sections. but at the last i have to reload table from section 2 to n number of sections. that is the main thing.

Answer (score 0):

There is a two ways to reload data. First - call reload data. It will refresh entire table view and and request load data from DataSource.

And second: add data manually triggering loading on necessary part of data source.

So basically if you don't want to reload all table, or want to have nice animations, you need to add new section first.

```
TblView.insertSections(IndexSet(integer: 1), with: .left)
```

Mind that you had to change data first, and then ask table view to query data for new section. It will automatically load data from data source.

Please take look for additional details at: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614892-insertsections

EDIT: I've noticed that you are trying to reload table in UIView.animation. It doesn't work that way. When you telling table view to add/remove/update data in it, you can specify desired animation, or it's .none

UPDATE: 
Example of code:

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
let toUpdateIndexSet = IndexSet(integersIn: 1 ..< tableView.numberOfSections)
tableView.reloadSections(toUpdateIndexSet, with: .fade)

if tableView.numberOfSections < self.numberOfSections(in: tableView) {
    let toAddIndexSet = IndexSet(integersIn: tableView.numberOfSections ..< self.numberOfSections(in: tableView))
    tableView.insertSections(toAddIndexSet, with: .right)
}
tableView.endUpdates()
```

Please mind that when you making changes, table view make attempt to reload content from data source. But if you for example had 1 section before update, than add second section and few rows to first section, and will try to reload first section, you will got crash (data source had two sections, but table view had only one at this time). 
So in this case you need  to make *batch update* - **beginUpdates**, insert new rows and add new section, **endUpdates**. 
In this case data source will be triggered only at endUpdates().

Comment: can you provide some example with my case. ? i.e first 2 section not able to reload and other will be and that all sections are depend on my search result.

Comment: By the way,  it is a good practice to place search field and any other static content as header of entire table view, instead of placing it as sections. You will get some nice uikit built-in features, reduce you code.

Answer (score -1):

First until a UITableView caches details of the number of sections so until you actually reload the UITableView numberOfSections will still produce the old value.

For example if you have a section array like this:

```
var sections: [Int] = [2, 1]
```

and this method:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return sections.count
}
```

that is used to provide the number of rows in a section and then did this:

```
sections.append(5)
print (tableView.numberOfSections)
tableView.reloadData()
print (tableView.numberOfSections)
```

you will get the result 2 and 3 because the numberOfSections is not updated until the table view reloads it's data.

Secondly because of the way that works you can only reload sections that already exist not new ones you are adding.  Instead you must work out the sections being added/removed and use the insertSections and deleteSections methods instead.

Thirdly why not just use:

```
self.TblView.reloadData()
```

and let it all be handled for you.

Comment: self.TblView.reloadData() i can not use because the 0 th section have search text field which also reload. and i loast what the text of search textfield. Can you please give example how insert/delete section or other ways to reload ?

Comment: Well the best thing would be to have something like a variable backing the search text field so that when the it reloads it just updates from the backing variable.  Otherwise you need to work out how the sections have changed and use the appropriate method.  So if before you had 2 sections and now you have 3 to call insertSections with an index set for just the 3rd section.  If you have 5 sections and you go down to 2 then you call deleteSections with an index set for 3, 4 and 5.

Comment: hmm..it's sound like better solution. but what about the keyboard hide / show?

Comment: What keyboard hide/show?  What problem is that going to cause?